# convert delimited values in a dictionary into a list of strings

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that looks like :

```
dict={'name':'ed|tom|pete','surname':'abc|def'}
```

How do I convert the keys with the delimeter | into a list ? Something that looks like:

```
dict1={'name':['ed','tom','pete'],'surname':['abc','def']}
```

thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through each keys and split it on the delimeter

```
for key in dict1.keys():
    dict1[key] = dict1[key].split('|')
```

**Sample Input:**

```
>>dict1={'name':'ed|tom|pete','surname':'abc|def'}
```

**Sample Output:**

```
>>dict1
{'name': ['ed', 'tom', 'pete'], 'surname': ['abc', 'def']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `dict-comprehension` along with `str.split`

```
values = {'name': 'ed|tom|pete', 'surname': 'abc|def'}
values = {k: v.split("|") for k, v in values.items()}
```